# Calculation with derived units (e.g. 1 hour * 1 miles/hour)

Tags: javascript, math, calculator

I have been trying to make a calculation with derived units, so far I have not got anywhere.

I have tried [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/index.html), but if I type `1 hour * 1 miles/hour`, I get `UnsupportedTypeError: Function divide(unit, unit) not supported`.

Can it be true that there really is no library for calculating with derived units?

Example of how it should work: `5 hour * 2 miles/hour = 10 miles`

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is kinda particular, what you want is to analize mathematical expressions and then get the results. You should probably need to create a syntax analizer

Comment: You might take a look at [js-quantities](https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities). I haven't used it but it seems to have support for compound quantities like m/s.

Comment: @Balder, I have really no idea how to do this.

Comment: @TedHopp, [js-quantities](https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities) can not work with derived units.

Comment: This small library is written for using with derived units: https://github.com/aktos-io/scada.js/blob/master/src/lib/aea/convert-units.ls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [js-quantities](https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities) can solve your problem, as long as you use the syntax of the framework:

```
Qty('5 hour').mul(Qty('2 miles/hour')).toString()
```

returns

```
"10 mi"
```